# Error when trying to extend a dataobject with addressable module (silverstripe)

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am currently trying to extend **Place** (custom dataobject) with silverstripe addressable module. However, I got the below error:

> [User Error] collateDataFields() I noticed that a field called 'LatLngOverride' appears twice in your form: '(unknown form)'. One is a 'CheckboxField' and the other is a 'CheckboxField'

Addressable module works for Page class object but not dataobject class.

Does anyone have any idea what is this error about?

Thanks.

Comment: To get the best results please share the portion of your code that this error references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who is facing this problem, the author has fixed it in the latest commit.
https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-addressable/commit/2dbd6f7013561e4135850ee81999ece22ca73498